# This command is unavailable because the license to use this application has expired - Excel Automation

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net, ole-automation

I have a .NET Windows application (which is written in VB.Net, but the same occurs with C#) where I am getting a `This command is unavailable because the license to use this application has expired` error.

The stack trace to this error is:
`at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Select()`

The line of code that is failing is: `wrksht.Range("A2").Select()`. It does not always fail! It can work several times before failing or can fail the first time it is called.

To be clear about how the process works:

1. A Word document is opened
2. A chart is found (via a shape)
3. The chart data is activated
4. The worksheet is accessed

```
Dim chrt As _word.Chart = shp.Chart
chrt.ChartData.Activate()
Dim wrksht As _excel.Worksheet = chrt.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
wrksht.Range("A2").Select() 'Line that errors
```

The Windows application is running on a Terminal Services instance and Office 365 is using a Shared Activation License (which is activated). The same application runs successfully on a standalone PC using Office 365, but with a standard license.

Any ideas?

**Additional Info**

I have created a simple macro in Word to bypass any .Net/application issues. The macro errors every time on the `.Select`. However, if I change the `.Select` to `.FormulaR1C1 = "TEST"`, then it completes. In fact all sorts of Word and Excel automation is working, it seems to only have issue with the `.Select` once the worksheet for the Word chart object is used.

See code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim wrksht As Excel.Worksheet

    Set shp = getInlineShapeFromTitle("Score_Graph_Question_15964_4")
    Set chrt = shp.Chart
    
    chrt.ChartData.Activate
    Set wrksht = chrt.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    'wrksht.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "TEST 1"
    wrksht.Range("A1").Select
    
    chrt.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
End Sub

Private Function getInlineShapeFromTitle(title As String) As InlineShape
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim shp1 As InlineShape
    
    For Each shp1 In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If shp1.title = title Then
            Set shp = shp1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    Set getInlineShapeFromTitle = shp
End Function
```

**Further Findings**

The Office license is valid and activated, however, when Word opens Excel (via the `chrt.ChartData.Activate` command), Excel has "Unlicensed Product" in the title bar. If Excel is opened manually, it shows as licensed and activated. This image shows what is shown when Word opens Excel:

[image: Image of Excel when opened by Word]

If I choose to set the datasource of the chart from Word manually (not using VBA), Excel opens and the unlicensed product message is not in the title bar.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2): _Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office._.

Comment: You may consider the possibility that you've somehow violated the MS licensing agreement and MS has intervened

Comment: Have you tried opening Excel on the computer (non-programmaticly)?

Comment: @user09938 Thanks for the responses. "Consideration for server-side...": I understand this in a webserver or equivalent environment, but this is terminal services where using Office is the norm. I am, as far as I can tell, following all the recommendations in the article. "License violation": How could I find out if that's the case? "Non-programatically": Yes. Excel and Word both function completely normally.

Comment: Not sure contact whoever manages your MS licensing.

Comment: Was your application previously running on the server or is this application new to this server? The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254207/license-expired-error-when-dynamically-generating-excel-docs-in-asp-net. (even though you're not using ASP.NET)

Comment: I saw that article before posting. I assume all Office components are installed as Excel & Word are fully functional. License being used is the Shared Activation License and is activated.

Comment: The application is new to the server.

Comment: _I assume all Office components are installed_: Perhaps your first mistake. In addition to verifying that the necessary components are installed, you should also verify the bitness (ie: 32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: Do you know what Office components would need to be installed to do a Select on an Excel range?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but according to [Overview of shared computer activation for Microsoft 365 Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-shared-computer-activation?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252f836f882c-8ff6-4f19-8b24-0212e0111c94#verify-that-shared-computer-activation-is-enabled): _There is a known issue where, on devices with both shared computer activation and viewer mode enabled, licensed users are incorrectly placed in viewer mode. This issue is fixed in Version 2205 and later._

Comment: We're running version 2301.

Comment: Until your most recent update, your post made no mention of "VBA". If you're using VBA add it to the tags. I'm not all that familiar with VBA, nor is it clear anymore what you are doing. If you haven't already done so, you may consider repairing Office (one of the features available when running the installer). Additionally, you need to update your post to reflect exactly what you are doing. How are you creating the Word document? How are you opening/modifying the Word document? Without the "VBA" tag, your post is unlikely to attract the attention of someone who is experienced with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but may be useful. It shows how you may do something similar without using late binding which allows one to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

**Add COM references** (Project => Add Reference... => COM)

- Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library
- Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library

**Add the following Imports statement**:

- `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop`

```
Private Sub Test(filename As String)
    Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Nothing
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document = Nothing

    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Throw New Exception($"Error - '{filename}' doesn't exist.")
    End If

    Try
        Debug.WriteLine($"filename: '{filename}'")

        'create new instance
        wordApp = New Word.Application()

        'open Word document
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(DirectCast(filename, Object))

        Dim chrt As Word.Chart = Nothing

        If wordDoc.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oShape As Word.InlineShape In wordDoc.InlineShapes
                chrt = oShape.Chart

                Debug.WriteLine($"Title: '{chrt.ChartTitle.Text}' ChartType: {chrt.ChartType.ToString()}")

                If chrt IsNot Nothing Then
                    chrt.ChartData.Activate()
                    excelWorkbook = DirectCast(chrt.ChartData.Workbook, Excel.Workbook)
                    excelWorksheet = DirectCast(excelWorkbook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

                    Debug.WriteLine($"Value: '{excelWorksheet.Range("A2").Cells().Value}'")

                    excelWorksheet.Range("B2").Select()
                    'excelWorksheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Test 1"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error - {ex.Message}")
        Throw
    Finally
        If excelWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
            'release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet)

            excelWorksheet = Nothing
        End If

        If excelWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
            excelWorkbook.Close(DirectCast(False, Object))

            'release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook)

            excelWorkbook = Nothing
        End If

        If wordDoc IsNot Nothing Then
            wordDoc.Close(DirectCast(False, Object))

            'release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordDoc)

            wordDoc = Nothing
        End If

        If wordApp IsNot Nothing Then
            wordApp.Quit()

            'release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordApp)

            wordApp = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Usage** (assumes there is a Button with the name 'ButtonRun')

```
Private Sub ButtonRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRun.Click
    Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd.Filter = "Word Document (*.docx)|*.docx"

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Test(ofd.FileName)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

**Resources**:

- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia)
- [Chart Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.chart?view=word-pia)
- [Chart.ChartData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.chart.chartdata?view=word-pia)
- [ChartData Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.chartdata?view=word-pia)
- [ChartData Workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.chartdata.workbook?view=word-pia#microsoft-office-interop-word-chartdata-workbook)
- [XlChartType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcharttype?view=excel-pia)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)
- [Interpolated Strings (Visual Basic Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings)

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a workaround and not necessarily a fix, but I am able to not get the error by turning off the "optional connected experiences" in Word's privacy settings:

[image: Word privacy settings to turn off optional connected experiences]

I don't know why this would be the case and it was found purely by luck. There must be some conflict between the Terminal Services instance and Office 365 using a Shared Activation License.

I found this article from MS for additional reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/privacy/optional-connected-experiences